# Using SharedArray and pmap in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, performance-testing, distributed, pmap

I am thinking about using distributed computation in a problem I face. Suppose I have an index `k` which increases from 1 to 800 (for instance). And for each `k`, I have a pool `p` which has large size and many numbers stored in it. I want to get `kth-pool` recursively. The protocol is like, if I know `(k-1)-th pool`, then I can randomly choose two values `z1, z2` from it and get a new value through a function `f` like `z = f(z1,z2)`. Then I store it into `k-th pool` and repeated this many times until this pool is full and then I try to get `(k+1)th-pool` from `kth-pool`.

Due to the large size of the pool, I try to use parallel computation to speed up my `Julia` code. I am trying to use `pmap` and use a `SharedArray` as my `(k-1)th-pool` within each `k`. So I write the following code

```
using Distributed
addprocs(10)

@everywhere using LinearAlgebra
@everywhere using StatsBase
@everywhere using Statistics
@everywhere using DoubleFloats
@everywhere using StaticArrays
@everywhere using SharedArrays
@everywhere using JLD
@everywhere using Dates
@everywhere using Random
@everywhere using Printf

@everywhere function rand_haar2(::Val{n}) where n
    M = @SMatrix randn(ComplexDF64, n,n) 
    q = qr(M).Q
    L = cispi.(2 .* @SVector(rand(Double64,n)))
    return q*diagm(L)
end

@everywhere function pool_calc(theta,pool::SharedArray,Np)

    Random.seed!(myid())

    pool_store = zeros(Double64,Np)

    Kup= @SMatrix[Double64(cos(theta)) 0; 0 Double64(sin(theta))]
    Kdown = @SMatrix[Double64(sin(theta)) 0; 0 Double64(cos(theta))]
    
    P2up = kron(@SMatrix[Double64(1.) 0.;0. 1.], @SMatrix[1 0; 0 0])
    P2down = kron(@SMatrix[Double64(1) 0;0 1],@SMatrix[0 0;0 1])

    poolcount = 0

    poolsize = length(pool)
    
    while poolcount < Np
        z1 = pool[rand(1:poolsize)]
        rho1 = diagm(@SVector[z1,1-z1])

        z2 = pool[rand(1:poolsize)]
        rho2 = diagm(@SVector[z2,1-z2])

        u1 = rand_haar2_slower(Val{2}())
        u2 = rand_haar2_slower(Val{2}())

        K1up = u1*Kup*u1'
        K1down = u1*Kdown*u1'
                
        K2up = u2*Kup*u2'
        K2down = u2*Kdown*u2'

        rho1p = K1up*rho1*K1up'
        rho2p = K2up*rho2*K2up'

        p1 = real(tr(rho1p+rho1p'))/2
        p2 = real(tr(rho2p+rho2p'))/2
                
        if rand()<p1
            rho1p = (rho1p+rho1p')/(2*p1)
        else 
            rho1p = K1down*rho1*K1down'/((1-p1)) 
        end

        if rand()<p2
            rho2p = (rho2p+rho2p')/(2*p2)
        else
            rho2p = K2down*rho2*K2down'/((1-p2))
        end
             
        rho = kron(rho1p,rho2p)

        U = rand_haar2_slower(Val{4}())
        rho_p = P2up*U*rho*U'*P2up'
        p = real(tr(rho_p+rho_p'))/2
             
        if rand()<p
            temp =(rho_p+rho_p')/2
                    
            rho_f = @SMatrix[temp[1,1]+temp[2,2] temp[1,3]+temp[2,4]; temp[3,1]+temp[4,2] temp[3,3]+temp[4,4]]/(p)
        else
            temp = P2down*U*rho*U'*P2down'
            rho_f = @SMatrix[temp[1,1]+temp[2,2] temp[1,3]+temp[2,4]; temp[3,1]+temp[4,2] temp[3,3]+temp[4,4]]/(1-p)
        end
        rho_f = (rho_f+rho_f')/2
        t = abs(tr(rho_f*rho_f))
        z = (1-t)/(1+abs(sqrt(2*t-1)))
        if !iszero(abs(z))
            poolcount = poolcount+1
            pool_store[poolcount] = abs(z)
        end
    end

    return pool_store

end

function main()

    theta = parse(Double64,ARGS[1])

    Nk = parse(Int,ARGS[2])

    S_curve = zeros(Double64,Nk)
    S_var = zeros(Double64,Nk)

    Npool = Int(floor(10^6))
    pool = SharedArray{Double64}(Npool)
    pool_sample = zeros(Double64,Npool)
    spool = zeros(Double64,Npool)

    pool .=0.5

    for k =1:800

        ret = pmap(Np->pool_calc(theta = theta,pool=pool,Np=Np),fill(10^5,10))
        pool_target = reduce(vcat,[ret[i][1] for i = 1:10])

        spool .=-pool_target .*log.(pool_target).-(1.0 .- pool_target).*log1p.(-pool_target)
            
        S_curve[k] = mean(spool)
            
        S_var[k] = (std(spool)/sqrt(Npool))^2

        pool = pool_target

    end
 

    label = @sprintf "%.3f" Float32(theta)

    save("entropy_real_128p_$(label)_ps6.jld","s", S_curve, "t", S_var)



end

main();
```

But I faced an error

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an MWE with your question rather than a full dump of your production code - otherwise it is hard to help. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `pmap`:

> `Note that f must be made available to all worker processes; see Code Availability and Loading Packages for details.`

The issue is that `Np->pool_calc(theta = theta,pool=pool,Np=Np)` is defining an anonymous function only on worker 1, but that function is being serialized by `pmap` to all the other workers, without the workers knowing how to execute it. Doing something like this should help:

```
@everywhere pool_calc_inner(Np) = pool_calc(theta = theta,pool=pool,Np=Np)
...
pmap(pool_calc_inner, fill(10^5,10))
```